# Android onClick Action

Tags: android

Fellas, I've been scratching my head trying to implement a fairly simple onClick action on a TextView to no success. Here is my code:

```
    public class AccountsActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;

     private TextView tvNextOkin;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_account);

        tvNextOkin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_acc_next_of_kin);
         tvNextOkin.setText("Not set. Tap here to add");
         tvNextOkin.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        }



        public void performClick(View view){
         Log.i("Action::", "clicked!!");

      // add  listener
      tvNextOkin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                  // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                  dialog.setTitle("This is a custom dialog");

                     dialog.show();
         }


         });
     }

 }
```

and here is the xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_acc_next_of_kin"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:text="tap here to add"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:textSize="14dp"
      android:onClick="performClick"
      android:typeface="sans" />

      </LinearLayout>

      </ScrollView>
```

My aim is to able to call the performClick() method when the textview is clicked. ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:clickable="true"` for `TextView` in xml

and as @ Altaf mentioned in his answer, remove the listener.
Just have,

```
public void performClick(View view){
     Log.i("Action::", "clicked!!");

              // custom dialog
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
     dialog.setTitle("This is a custom dialog");

     dialog.show();
 }
```

Or alternate way is to remove the `android:onClick="onClick"`
and implement the `onClickListener` for the `TextView` in your activity.

Comment: U r welcome @user2251344. Do vote up if you found the ans useful :-) oh thanks you did that already

Answer (score 0):

Remove listener

```
tvNextOkin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {}
```

You just need performClick method

Answer (score 0):

you should register your onClick listener in onCreate().
You can reference Android SDK document.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your xml for textview

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

and perfrom onclick operation

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
      }
```

Comment: Nice one, Aravinth! indeed i forgot to add android:clickable="true" in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your problem.

When you set **android:onClick="performClick"**, It mean, when user click to TextView the method performClick will be invoked.

In this method will do: SET onClickListener for **tvNextOkin**

It doesn't show any dialog. :D

**The solution:**

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_acc_next_of_kin"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:text="tap here to add"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:textSize="14dp"
      android:typeface="sans" />

tvNextOkin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                  // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                  dialog.setTitle("This is a custom dialog");

                     dialog.show();
}
```

Do not put it in **performClick** method.

Hope this will help you.

Regards,