# Populating contacts listvew from SQLite - no contacts displayed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am starting to learn software development by modifying examples. Right now I am making a list of contact and I want to populate it from local SQLite db, by modifying [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) tutorial and instead of getting data from json I wanted do get data from my local db. I have a local database with a number of contacts.

This is my problem: ***when I open my contacts list, the progress dialog keeps spinning, and there are no contacts displayed***.

Here is my code:

SQLiteHandler:

```
public List<Contact> getMyContactDetails() {
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setUserName(cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME)));
                contact.setThumbnailUrl(cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(IMAGE)));
                contacts.add(contact);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

ContactListAdapter:

```
public class ContactsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Contact> contactItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public ContactsListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Contact> contactItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.contactItems = contactItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return contactItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_contact, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageview_profile);
        TextView userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_username);

        // getting contact data for the row
        Contact m = contactItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // userName
        userName.setText(m.getUserName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

ContactListActivity:

```
public class ContactsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView listView;
    private ContactsListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
        adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, contactList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        pDialog.show();

        SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
        contactList = db.getMyContactDetails();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call notify data changed method of your adapter once fetching contacts from database completes.

Comment: Please look at my solution with below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170095/onitem-click-functionality-to-contact-application-in-android/40170446#40170446

Comment: You have a method `hidePDialog()`. Looks like you (almost) never call it, so "the progress dialog keeps spinning" until the activity is destroyed. And @Febi Mathew is right about `Adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While initializing adapter the list is empty so you need to fetch data from DB first

```
// show dialog
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
pDialog.show();

// fetch the data first 
SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
contactList = db.getMyContactDetails();    

// now the list has data so display it
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, contactList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// dismiss the dialog 
hidePDialog();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to **hide dialog after fetching data**. Currently you are hiding it in `onDestroy`

Answer (score 3):

I found 2 mistakes

1. You never called hidePDialog(); only you are calling it on the onDestroy method. So the ProgressDialog is spinning.
2. You get contacts from the db but not load to the listview.

Change code like this

```
SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
        contactList = db.getMyContactDetails();
 adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, contactList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Need Some more info :

1. Have to copied all contact from AndroidDB to your localDb.
2. if Yes. Check your DB once.
3. if ur LocalDb has contacts 
   then change your code :

   SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
       contactList = db.getMyContactDetails();
       adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, contactList);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

or

```
SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(this.getApplicationContext());
    contactList = db.getMyContactDetails();
```

add this below line after the above line.

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

later call for `hidePDialog();` because you are not stopping the dialog any where except destroy()